# Unity dash does not get keyboard focus first time

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, focus

When I login to a unity session, the first time I press the Super key, the dash pops up but the keyboard focus does not go to it. I press the Super key a second time to dismiss the dash, and a third time to bring it back, and now it has the keyboard focus and I can type away happily. Every time after that the dash gets the keyboard focus as I expect it to. Anyone got any idea why? Or how to fix it?

I am using Natty/11.04 and I upgraded to Natty during the beta period which might have made the difference. (I am still using Natty) This behaviour has been the same since I upgraded and started using Unity.

**Edit:** As suggested by the first answer, I have now filed a [bug about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/861738).

Comment: Wait, are you using 11.04 or 11.10? Your question is somewhat fuzzy as to that point... :)

Comment: @jrg - I have clarified the version - it is still 11.04

Comment: The linked bug has since been marked as a duplicate of this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/860805 Either way, bug reports are offtopic for Ask Ubuntu. Regardless, thanks for taking the time to report it!

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/860805) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you think this is a configurable feature and wonder how to disable the bug, you should file bugs on Launchpad.net. This site is meant for questions and answers and your question is quite clearly more of a bug report than a question.

Since you're talking about keyboard focus, I guess maybe you're talking about the Dash and not the Launcher. The launcher is the strip of icons on the left side of your screen. The Dash is the one where you search for files, apps, music, etc. (In order to help you file a bug). Please provide as much details in the report as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem up until 2 or 3 days ago. It was solved by one of the latest updates that came with Ubuntu. It not only fixed this problem but also the other problem about right clicking an unity panel icon and not being able to select the context many the first time but only after doing it again. So both problems that do not get keyboard or mouse focus have been solved by the latest update.

Already checked in 2 laptops (Toshiba and HP) and on my Intel Desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done the latest updates in 11.10 and, as I type this, my launcher's focus is behind the Firefox window in which I am typing this. It's also behind Gimp and Thunderbird. It's useless to work like this, so I am forced to log out and log in after typing this.

Comment: You could just minimize your windows or use Ctrl+Alt+arrow key to switch to another workspace. The dash/launcher should still be perfectly accessible after all the windows have been (temporarily) cleared off the screen, no logout necessary.

Comment: I "could" do that, yes, but that's not the point. The point is that it's not the intended behaviour and logging out and back in seems to be better in the long run (as opposed to minimising multiple times while hunting down the dash).